# How be notified only when CoreData object(s) change?

Tags: ios, core-data

Each time I synchronise with my server, I refresh all fields of my CoreData objects.

Even if nothing changes I still receive `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` elsewhere in my code.

- Is this expected behaviour?
- How can I prevent this and only be notified when something has actually changed?

When I add below code after refreshing an object, things work as I want. But why can't CoreData sort this out?

```
if (object.changedValues.count == 0)
{
    [object.managedObjectContext refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

- Yes, even though values aren't changing new *writes* are still happening in *Managed Object Context*. So, `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` are expected to be fired.

Consider using a [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller) as:

```
@interface CoreDataHelper : NSObject < NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate >

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

@end

@implementation
@synthesize context = _context;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static CoreDataHelper *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [self new];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)context{

    if (_context != nil) {
        return _context;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator]; // you know what goes in PSC here, right?
    if (!coordinator) {
        NSLOG(@"Argh! coordinator == nil");
        return nil;
    }

    _context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _context;
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller{
/*
This function will be invoked by the OS whenever a Managed Object changes.
Keep in mind that this will be invoked on the Managed Object Context Queue.
This is the place where your logic to be performed whenever a object changes needs to be.
*/
}

@end
```

// Now in your file

```
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance].context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

fetchedResultsController.delegate = [CoreDataHelper sharedInstance];

NSError *error;
if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]){
    NSLOG(@"fetch error %@", error);
}
```

Now, since we have hooked up `self` as delegate of `fetchedResultsController`, `self` needs to conform to the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol. 
You choose to override any of the optional methods, most straight-forward being:
`- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller`

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but view controllers are not involved so this does not help me. Is there no way to avoid the notification other than testing `changedValues` on each object and discarding the non-changes?

Comment: Well, `self` can be any instance of NSObject class, not necessarily (& even generally)  a UIViewController. You can have a Core Data Helper singleton or a simple instance of a class like `@interface CoreDataHelper : NSObject`

Comment: I give up: You're still showing `NSFetchedResultsController` and you just write `the magic of db updates`, but that's my only question. So it's a lot of useless code and no answer.

Comment: @meaning-matters `controllerDidChangeContent:` will be invoked whenever any managed object _changes_. At that point, you can perform your operations to be executed, the ones which you were executing on listening to `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`

Comment: Is your `controllerDidChangeContent` in only called for REAL changes, and not for CoreData object updates that did not change any of the fields? If so, please explain why.

Comment: @meaning-matters There is a difference between our perceived REAL changes & changes which Core Data observes. Even though the VALUE of an attribute remains the same, by parsing it, a new WRITE operation has been triggered. And since a new WRITE has happened in the database, `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` will be fired as well as `controllerDidChangeContent:` will be invoked!

Comment: Don't you see that your code does not help me one bit then??? It only add a lot of stuff, which I don't even need. I can't believe you even wrote the above.

Comment: Some other day. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: What? So you just wrote something?